# jax rs client blocking input stream read

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, inputstream

I am working on a JAX-RS client application (using resteasy-client 3.0.8Final) which should read the (text) output streamed by a REST service and simply print it line-by-line on the console.

A manual curl call to the service confirms that the output is streamed correctly, line-by-line, as expected. However, when I try to read it from within the java client, it appears that I can only read (and thus display) from the input stream once the stream is closed and the call to the service has completed. In other words, if the service emits one line of output every second or so, instead of being able to display one line every second, I have to wait until the call to the service completes and then all lines are displayed at once. Here's the code which handles the response:

```
final InputStream is = (InputStream)response.readEntity(InputStream.class);
final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(is)));

try
{
    String line;

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(line);
        System.out.flush();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
}
```

I would expect the call to `readLine` to block and wait for a new line to become available, but it appears to be waiting for the InputStream to be closed (in another thread?) before reading, but my understanding is obviously faulty.

Does someone see what I am missing?

Comment: What message do you send from Java client? Does it include more than one line terminators? Because readLine() will wait for the end of the line.